# Evaluating normal distribution integral

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

How one can show that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{2.92}e^{-x^2/2}dx=0.99825$$

Comment: Approximate this as $$1 - \int_{2.92}^N e^{-x^2/2} dx$$ where $N$ is big, e.g. $10$. Then use your favorite numerical method.

Comment: Well, it is not a strict equality, only an approximation. There're multiple numerical methods, both deterministic and probabilistic.

Comment: As far as I know, it can only be evaluated by using numerical approach. Since the integral that you have is the CDF of standard normal distribution then you only look the value of $\Pr[X\le2.92]$ in the $Z$-table.

Comment: I have two tables, one gives approximation 0.9982 and other 0.9983 an WA gave 0.99825. I would like to know which approximation is the best.

Comment: @curious The WA approximation is most likely computed overly precise and then rounded correctly, thus I'd consider it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the [Gaussian integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianIntegral.html)

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2 / 2} dx = 1$$

can be computed directly, so it's a little easier to try approximating

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{2.92}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2} dx$$

Due to the very fast decay of the exponential function, it's a pretty good estimate to just compute

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{2.92}^{10} e^{-x^2/2} dx$$

which [can be approximated as](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%281/sqrt%282pi%29%29%20e%5E%28-x%5E2%20/%202%29%20from%202.92%20to%2010) $0.00175$ (using your favorite numerical method, e.g. Simpsons' rule). To estimate the error involved in this approximation, note that

$$\int_{10}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2} dx < \int_{10}^{\infty} e^{-5x} dx \sim 10^{-22}$$

where we have used that $x^2 > 10x$ for $x > 10$.