# Evaluating a cumulative distribution function from normal distribution

Tags: numerical-methods

How one can prove by using only pencil and paper that
$$0.99815<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{2.92}e^{-x^2/2}dx<0.99825?$$
I think there is a mistake in my book which says that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{2.92}e^{-x^2/2}dx\approx 0.9983.$$

Comment: R gives `pnorm(2.92)` as $0.9982498$ so $0.9983$ would be rounding the wrong way (just)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't note that this is a duplicate, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748535/evaluating-normal-distribution-integral?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into Abramowitz/Stegun, p.932, eq. 26.2.12 one finds  the asymptotic approximation (Mill's ratio):

$ Q(x) = \frac{Z(x)}{x}+R_1$

where
 $Q(x)=1- \int_{-\infty}^{x} Z(y) dy$ 
with $Z(y)$ the standard normal density,
i.e. your integrand. It says further that $|R_1| < Z(x)/x^3$.
So just check the error bound.

Comment: I doubt this; $Z(2.92)$ is quite small. You must mean something different. Ok, I checked now you mean $1-Z(2.92)/2.92$.

Comment: My mistake - forgot to subtract from 1, so: $1-\phi(2.92)/2.92 \approx 0.9980767$

Comment: @Henry, your result is ok.